# Ursprung von »zum Halse heraushängen«

Tags: etymology, idiom

Die Bedeutung der Redewendung ist klar. Im *Duden Online* findet man die Redewendung unter [Hals](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hals_Koerperteil_Rachen), jedoch ohne Angabe des Ursprungs:

> etwas hängt/wächst jemandem zum Hals[e] heraus (umgangssprachlich: jemand ist einer Sache überdrüssig: dein ewiges Gejammere hängt mir zum Hals heraus; geht von der Tatsache aus, dass Tieren, die sich überfressen haben, das letzte Stück zum Hals heraushängen kann)

Im [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=etwas%20h%C3%A4ngt%20einem%20zum%20Hals%20raus&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) ist sie auch aufgeführt, ebenfalls ohne Angabe einer Erstverwendung oder früher Vorkommnisse:

> umgangssprachlich; Die Wendung bezieht sich auf den Vorgang des Erbrechens unverdaulicher Nahrung

Diese beiden Erklärungen widersprechen sich offenkundig.

Das [deutsche Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etwas_h%C3%A4ngt_einem_zum_Hals_raus) nennt auch keinen Ursprung, weiß aber immerhin, dass es im Niederländischen eine ähnliche Formulierung gibt:

> dat hangt iemand de keel uit

Als Ergänzung aus den Kommentaren füge ich noch hinzu, dass die Redewendung auch im [Grimm (unter Hals 11a)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH01438#XGH01438) verzeichnet ist, was auf ihr höheres Alter hindeutet:

> eine speise von der man zuviel genossen hat oder deren man überdrüssig ist, steht bis an den hals, was man nachher auch freier und bildlich von einer widerwärtigen sache behauptet; das bild wird sogar kräftig gesteigert, indem man sagt ich habe nun jene speise so oft essen müssen, dasz sie mir zum halse heraus hängt, zum halse heraus wächst;

Gibt es eine anerkannte Quelle für diese Redewendung?

Comment: Spannende Frage! Ich hatte immer angenommen, das bezieht sich auf die Zunge, die Mensch und Tier nach monotoner & anstrengender Arbeit zum Hals heraushängt...

Comment: Danke, habe es ergänzt!

Comment: "*Diese beiden Erklärungen widersprechen sich offenkundig.*" nicht unbedingt, wenn Föllerei zu Erbrechen führt.

Comment: Was ist in Hinsicht auf eine Redewendung "eine anerkannte Quelle"? Ein (lex.) Werk? Ein Autor? Wenn du mir sagst, was dich u.U. zufriedenstellen könnte, schreib ich u.U. hier rein, was es zu sagen gäbe.

Comment: @multiplexetliber Ich hatte mich gefragt, ob die Redewendung einem Werk entstammt, ähnlich dem bekannten Satz aus »Götz von Berlichingen« oder anderen heute üblichen Ausdrücken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lücken bei Grimm lassen sich manchmal schließen durch einen Sprung zurück in der Zeit. Adelung {1} nennt eine ganze Reihe von Redewendungen mit *Hals*, alle "figürlich [...], aber nur im gemeinen Leben, höchstens nur in der vertraulichen Sprechart üblich […]", nicht jedoch die von dir nachgefragte. Er schließt die Aufzählung mit dem Satz: "Und was dergleichen niedrige Arten des Ausdruckes mehr sind." Wie so oft bei Adelung bleibt in der Schwebe, ob der Satz einen Zustand beschreibt, also deskriptiv ist, oder eine Handlungsempfehlung enthält, also normativ ist. Nicht beantwortbar ist Frage, ob die Rw. einem Verzicht Adelungs auf weitere Niederungen der Sprache zum Opfer gefallen ist oder in den 1770-er-Jahren noch nicht existiert hat.

Ein Blick über den Tellerrand hinaus liegt nahe, das WNT {2}. Als Belegstellen für *iets hangt iemand de keel uit* werden genannt: Arend Fokke Simonsz. *Boertige Reis door Europa* (1794-1806), Jacob van Lennep. *De Lotgevallen van Klaasje Zevenster* (1865-66) sowie Louis Couperus. *Eline Vere* (1889) {3}. Die Angabe 1794 ff. sagt nur bedingt etwas über den Zeitpunkt des Entstehens der ndl. Rw., alle drei sagen wenig über ihre Frequenz im Schriftwerk und nichts über ihre Verbreitung und Frequenz in gesprochener Sprache im Alltag. Sie sagen auch nichts über den Zeitpunkt des Entstehens der dtsch. Rw. oder ihres ersten Auftauchens im Druck. Gleichzeitig steht fest, dass diese vor 1877, dem Erscheinungsjahr von Bd. 10 des Grimm, so frequent, den Verfassern so geläufig gewesen sein muss, dass sie die Aufnahme wert war. Ob eine Belegstelle aus Gründen der Schicklichkeit oder aus Platzgründen fehlt oder ob das Fehlen schlicht am Korpus liegt, lässt sich vermutlich nicht mehr eruieren.

Eine Annäherung an den Entstehungszeitpunkt bzw. -raum ist möglich. Wander {4}, Bd. 2 von 1870, kennt, wenn auch nicht komplett wortgleich: *Er (es) wächst mir zum Halse heraus*, mit der Erklärung "Seine aufdringliche Gegenwart erregt mir Ueberdruss, Ekel. Auch von Dingen, die lästig sind.".  Wander verweist auf Tendlau (1860) {5}, der die Rw. identisch anführt. Belegstellen nennen beide nicht. Vorausgesetzt, dass Wander und Tendlau *es **hängt** mir …* nicht übersehen, vergessen oder weggelassen haben, ist aus dem *wachsen* von vor 1860 (Tendlau) das bis heute übliche *hängen* von vor 1877 geworden (Grimm). Oder hat sich, zu welchem Zeitpunkt auch immer, nicht das Verb geändert, sondern es ist zur Rw. mit *wachsen* eine weitere mit *hängen* dazugekommen, eine Übernahme aus dem Ndl.? Oder sind *het hangt me de keel uit* und *es hängt mir zum Hals(e) heraus* unabhängig voneinander entstanden, ndl. früher als dtsch.? Die Fragen lassen sich nicht ohne weiteres beantworten und dürfen in diesem Kontext auch offen bleiben. {6}

Sicher hingegen ist, dass die Redewendungen in beiden Sprachen keine Übernahmen aus dem Frz. sind, denn da wurde das Zuviel des Schlechten in die genau entgegengesetzte Richtung hinausbefördert: *il me sortit par le cul*. - Das *Schweizerische Idiotikon* (1881 ff.) {7} weiß nichts von etw., das jdm. heraushängt, weder aus dem *Hals* noch aus der *Cheel*. *Deutsche Sprichwörter und Redewendungen im Sprachwandel. Online-Lexikon zur diachronen Phraseologie des Deutschen in neuhochdeutscher Zeit*, ebenfalls Schweiz, kennt die Rw., sie ist dort jedoch noch nicht bearbeitet.

Bis hierher dies. Du siehst, dass die Antwort auf eine scheinbar simple Frage zur Sprachgeschichte, hier: zu einem Phrasem und seiner Verwendungsgeschichte, ganz essentiell von der Dokumentations- bzw. Aufarbeitungslage abhängt. Wie unterschiedlich die Lagen sind, zeigt das Vorhergehende. Deutlich geworden ist auch, dass allerlei Angaben immer nur begrenzte Aussagekraft haben. Der "Ursprung" der Rw., mithin letztlich Derjenige, der's als Erster **gesagt** hat, bleibt in diesem Fall hinter dem Nebel der Zeit verborgen. {8}

---

{1} Johann Christoph Adelung. Grammatisch-kritisches Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart (1774-86)

{2} Woordenbook der Nederlandsche Taal (1864-1998; 3 Ergänzungsbände 2001), insgesamt 43 Bde.

{3} Ein paar Worte zur Einbettung. Bereits der Titel 'Burleske / Derb-komische Reise durch Europa', ein siebenbändiges Werk aus dem literarisch-humoristischen Genre, weist darauf hin, dass hier auch sprachlich nicht immer alles 'adrett' ist. Van Lenneps Roman 'Die Erlebnisse / Die Abenteuer von Klaasje Siebenstern' verursachte einen noch nie dagewesenen Skandal, handelt er doch von einem Findelkind, das als Jugendliche in einem Bordell landet. Der Roman erreichte hohe Auflagen. Im Vergleich ist *Eline Vere* harmlos, aber der Naturalismus war nun einmal kein Schauplatz von Überfeinerung.

{4} Karl Friedrich Wilhelm Wander. Deutsches Sprichwörter-Lexikon (1866-80), 5 Bde.

{5} Abraham Moses Tendlau. Sprichwörter und Redensarten deutsch-jüdischer Vorzeit. Als Beitrag zur Volks-, Sprach-, und Sprichwörter-Kunde (1860)

{6} Dessen ungeachtet bleibt dir die Möglichkeit, der dtsch. Rw. weiter nachzuspüren, z.B. bei Wilhelm Körte. Die Sprichwörter und sprichwörtlichen Redensarten der Deutschen (1837); Johann J.H. Bücking. Versuch einer medicinischen und physikalischen Erklärung deutscher Sprichwörter und sprichwörtlicher Redensarten (1797) bis hin zu Jesko Friedrich. Phraseologisches Wörterbuch des Mittelhochdeutschen. Redensarten, Sprichwörter und andere feste Wortverbindungen in Texten von 1050-1350 (2006). Weitere Wb. findest du möglicherweise im KVK; https://kvk.bibliothek.kit.edu/?digitalOnly=0&embedFulltitle=0&newTab=0

{7} Schweizerisches Idiotikon. Schweizerdeutsches Wörterbuch (1881 ff.). Der abschließende 17. Bd. dürfte in absehbarer Zeit erscheinen.

{8} Das ist anders bei Wörten wie z.B. *Denkzettel, Ebenbild, Lästermaul, lichterloh, Lockvogel, Machtwort, Muttersprache* oder Fügungen/Wendungen wie *etw. ausposaunen, im Dunkeln tappen, ein Herz und eine Seele, der große Unbekannte, für immer und ewig, die Zähne zusammenbeißen*, von denen wir sehr genau wissen, dass sie allesamt Neuschöpfungen Luthers sind.